# run docker in jenkins container (docker in docker)

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-docker

Im trying to run docker inside jenkins container, i used this command to create jenkins container

`docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker jenkins/jenkins:latest`

then this command to access jenkins container bash
`docker exec -u 0 -it <container-id> bash`, whenever i run `docker` i get this error

`` docker: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by docker) docker: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by docker) ``

What is creating this problem and what ways in order to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by downgrading my server OS to Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 2):

This is not reliable anymore, because the Docker Engine is no longer distributed as (almost) static libraries.

so run `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  jenkins/jenkins:latest`

then this command to access jenkins container bash as root user `docker exec -u 0 -it <container-id> bash`

Once inside the Jenkins container, simply run this command to install docker inside of the Jenkins container: `curl https://get.docker.com/ > dockerinstall && chmod 777 dockerinstall && ./dockerinstall`
this command gets the docker quick installation script and runs the script which then installs docker inside of the container

Exit out of the Jenkins container interactive shell, and run the following command to change permissions on “docker.sock” for added security `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: actually i solved it by downgrading my server OS to Ubuntu 18